# All but MPlayer and VLC unable to play MP4 video?

Tags: gnome, video

I have a specific MP4 video file that plays fine in MPlayer and VLC, but other programs on my Arch Linux box (Banshee, Gnome's Movie Player) are unable to play it. Most seem to treat it as having zero length. It also causes Gnome's Properties dialog to just display a dialog saying "Creating Properties Window" and never load.

What is it about this file that causes it to do this?

Comment: We'd have to see the file, and even then this is probably simply a bug in xine/gstreamer

Comment: Or a misencoded file that mplayer and vlc happen to be able to handle

Comment: Can't upload the file, given that it's a full movie, sorry.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This appears to be because of a misencoded file. Encoding with a different application than originally used did not have the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You've installed the needed gstreamer plugins?
(don't know exactly which, maybe **gstreamer0.10-bad** or **gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg**) ...